# Grub rescue error: no such partition

Tags: grub2

I dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.13. they worked just fine until I got an update on Ubuntu, it needed me to close all processes. I decided to use the `kill all -u` command, which just ruined my Ubuntu side, due to errors (I have learned my lesson). Since I had windows 10, I decided to delete the Ubuntu side using disk manager, which comes by default. After my double stupid moves, to sum it up, I turned the computer off, and when I turn it on, this comes up:

```
error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.13? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your PC is UEFI and both systems have been installed in such mode you can still boot Windows by changing the default boot at UEFI settings.
2. Otherwise you need to boot from Windows recovery media and follow instruction to repair the Windows bootloader.

There's no other way in case #2 because files required for boot resided on the partition you just deleted. One more lesson learned, I suppose.

Comment: yes, all lessons learned. I  have a few quick questions:  1.when i boot from UEFI i get a menu were i get to chose the device (usbs, etc) i want to boot, is that normal? cant i just boot into windows? 2.How do i boot into windows recovery media? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, that's normal and how UEFI works. You would be making a USB flash drive like you do for a Linux distro and boot from there, if you need to run recovery. Not needed if all was in UEFI mode, in which case just select the Windows entry instead. How you can make that the default option varies and depends on the hardware.